# DotNetCore 3.1 site with Plesk Obsidian for Windows

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, plesk

Has anyone had any success getting a DotNetCore 3.1 site to work with Plesk Obsidian for Windows, like through out-of-process hosting?

If so, may I know what are the things I need to do to make this work?

I tried to set web.config to OutOfProcess, but I'm still getting an ANCM error.

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll"
stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
```

[Plesk Obsidian works on 2.2](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000442805-ASP-NET-Core-versions-in-Plesk), but I was thinking whether it can work with 3.1 if it is out of process. We would like to move to 3.1 because any lower version is no longer officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Plesk on Asphostportal hosting here. As I know that Plesk doesn't officially support .net core on their control panel. So, you must ask your hosting provider to setup .net core for you on the server. You need to setup your application pool to No Managed Code in order to run .net core. Please make sure that your provider has installed [.net core bundled on their server](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

Comment: Yes the provider has installed the bundle. I have also unticked ASP.Net in Hosting Settings (for No Managed Code).

Comment: What is the error message? Have you asked this issue to your provider?